# Discord.py Bot doesn't respond to commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm currently trying to create a discord music bot and im coding it in vsc; however, when I try to run a command, none of them work although I think the code is more or less right. I was wondering whether anyone could help me. Please and Thank you.

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN ='' 
#client(the bot)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

#commands and stuff
@client.command()
async def play(context, url : str ):
   voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name='General') #voiceChannel=ctx.message.author.voice.channel 
   voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
   if not voice.is_connected():
       await voiceChannel.connect()

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("uwuowo is currently not connected to a voice channel")

@client.command()
async def pause(context):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.pause
    else:
        await ctx.send("no songs are currently playing")

@client.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_paused():
        voice.resume
    else:
        await ctx.send("audio is currently playing")

@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
     voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
     voice.stop

#run the client on the server               
client.run(TOKEN)```
````

Comment: Could you show us the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Those parentheses next to your decorators might be the culprit, try getting rid of those. Also, not a good idea to post your token where other people can see ;)

Comment: Please write the complete solution, to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using ctx instead of context

```
#commands and stuff
@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url : str ):
```